# Excel Lazy Evaluation for AND() and OR()

Tags: excel, lazy-evaluation

Excel appears to not use lazy evaluation for AND() and OR() functions. For example:

```
=AND(A1<>0, B1/A1>.5)
```

will result in a value of #DIV/0!. One alternative would be to use an if statement:

```
=IF(A1<>0, B1/A1>.5, FALSE)
```

however this becomes messy if the AND function was planned to be used inside an IF function (or possible some nested IFs). Is there a better (i.e. more readable) solution?

Comment: I haven't found anything simpler yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can do much better than what you've got. Here's a few other alternatives:

```
=IF(A1,B1/A1>.5) 
=IFERROR(B1/A1>.5,FALSE)
=COUNT(N(A1<>0),N(B1/A1>.5))=2
```

Although it's longer, the last one can be extended to more conditions and is easily modified to OR by changing `=2` to `>0`.